# Show characters in from one textbox in another

Tags: c#

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string c;
            string a;
            int b = 0;
            foreach (char m in textBox1.Text)
            {
                b++;
                a = m.ToString();
                if (a=="a"&&b==1)
                {
                    textBox2.Text = "Error";
                }
                c = m.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = c;



            }
        }
```

Hello
i want to type something in textbox1 and see the characters of textbox1 in textbox2 
for Example:
type "Hello" in textbox1 and see "H e l l o" in textbox2 but i see the last char of the textbox1 "o" in textbox2

what should i do?

Comment: btw, you are using too much variables. `c` is not necessary, because `a` has the same value with it.

Comment: @Mlad If my answer has helped you, please mark it as answer

Comment: @nemanja228 i dont test it because i cant underestand it im begiiner

Comment: You add an event handler to TextBox.TextChange the same way like you add buttonClick to button :) Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 textBox2.Text = c;
```

This overrides the textBox2. Try

```
 textBox2.Text += c;
```

Edit:As you are a student, Im going to simplify.

For spaces, replace the upper line to:

```
if(b==1)//that means this is first char of your textbox. And we wont add spaces.
{
    textBox2.Text+=c;
}
else//that means its not first, and we need to add spaces.
{
    textBox2.Text+= ' '+c;
}
```

But there are some things that you need to aware:

- `c` is redundant as i said in comment. Try to replace all `c`'s to `a`'s, including solution
- This answer is simpler, but @BoredomOverload's answer is better. Consider using that.

Comment: but how can i write it with space like this H e l l o

Comment: @Miad you could use my answer. I implemented the spacing and the validation that the first character can't be `a`.

Comment: @BoredomOverload awesome it works successfully but i dont undrestand what this line "if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) return;" doing.

Comment: @miad "return" exits the method. The rest checks whether the text in textBox1 is null (will not happen) or is just whitespace/empty. So if there is nothing to do, just skip the rest

Answer (score 3):

You could use `string.Join()` and do it in one go:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox1.Text)) return;

    if(textBox1.Text[0] == 'a')
    {
        textBox2.Text = "Error";
        return;
    }

    textBox2.Text = string.Join(" ", textBox1.Text.ToCharArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it automatically with TextChanged event handling:

```
textBox1.TextChanged += TextBox1_TextChanged; //set up this first

void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text1WithSpaces = string.Join(" ", textBox1.Text.ToCharArray());
    textBox2.Text = text1WithSpaces;
}
```